# Gradle/TestNG: split log for concurrent tests

Tags: jenkins, gradle, testng

I am executing tests concurrently on jenkins using gradle.

```
test {
  useTestNG {
    setParallel('classes')
    setThreadCount(4)  
  }
}
```

Everything runs great, but when test fails I see related jenkins log messed up with output from other threads. Is there a way that I can have for every test separated output?

*UPD*
It has nothing to do with jenkins, output logs already messed up in gradle.